# ColdFusion Query Output Displaying Variable Name Instead Of Field Value

Tags: sql, coldfusion

I'm an "old dog" and largely self-taught on this stuff and can usually make things work (primative and convoluted as it might be), but this is the first thing that has me really stymied.

I didn't want to burden everyone with a lot of stuff to try to explain, but, here is perhaps a better explanation and example:

(@Leigh - and thank you for your time and help!) - The query is dynamic because what I desire to have is a single "universal" page combination (form page plus accompanying action page) that is used to edit multiple different (but fairly similar) record sets (so that I don't have to write a whole bunch of individual form/action page pairs).

When this "universal" "change" form page is invoked, it is passed the "ID" variable for the particular record to be edited, along with a "listID" variable unique to the particular record set containing the record to be edited.

Using the "URL.listID", the form page then looks at a pre-defined included list of record set variables (datasource, query table, field for column 1, field for column 2, etc.) pertaining to the value of the "listID" and sets (using  ) the dynamic variables.  Example - if "listID" is "5", which has only one column:

```
<cfif #URL.listID# EQ 5>
  <cfset page_title = 'Change Member Role Picklist'>
  <cfset datasource = '#Session.db_docs#'>
  <cfset query_tbl = 'tblMemberRole'>
  <cfset columns = 1>
  <cfset column1_label = 'Member Role'>
  <cfset column1_field = "role">
  <cfset column1_input_type = "text">
  <cfset column1_input_size = "100">
  <cfset column1_input_maxlength = "100">
</cfif>
```

The query uses those variables ("ID" plus the others it got from the above list) to retrieve the individual record to be edited, and populate the "change" form.

Run query:

```
<cfquery name="cfqGetItem" datasource="#datasource#">
 SELECT * 
 FROM #query_tbl# 
 WHERE ID = <cfqueryparam value="#URL.ID#" cfsqltype="cf_sql_integer">  
</cfquery>
```

My "change" form (abbreviated here without table HTML) to be populated would be:

```
<form name="form_item_chg" action="chg_item2.cfm" method="post" enctype="multipart/form-data">

  <input type="text" name="#column1_field#" maxlength="#column1_input_maxlength#" size="#column1_input_size#" value="#cfqGetItem[column1_field][currentRow]#">

  <input type="Submit" value="Post Changes">
</form>
```

However, instead of the "change" form being populated with the VALUE for field "role", it instead is trying to use the variable name "column1_field", which it says is (true, of course) undefined in the query.

When I tried "#cfqGetItem[column1_field][currentRow]#", it says "Variable currentrow is not defined".

When I tried "#cfqGetItem.column1_field#", it says "Element column1_field is not defined in query cfqGetItem".

I apologize in advance for not knowing/using all the correct terminology, and hope I am explaining this reasonably clearly.  I suspect I will have to revert to writing individual form-page/action-page pairs.  Thank you to all for your time and help!

---

ORIGINAL POST:
I'm not highly technical, and this is probably something simple, but here is

my dilemma, where I am attempting to retrieve a single record using a variable name in the query.

First, I define some variables:

```
<cfset ID = #Form.ID#<!--- the single record I want to retrieve, passed from a form --->

<cfset datasource = 'MyDatabase'>
<cfset query_tbl = 'MyDatabaseTable'>
<cfset field1 = 'actual_fieldname1'><!--- field in MyDatabaseTable --->
<cfset field2 = 'actual_fieldname2'><!--- field in MyDatabaseTable --->
```

ETC.

Then, to retrieve this single record, I run a query using those variables:

```
<cfquery name="cfqGetItem" datasource="#datasource#">
  SELECT * 
  FROM #query_tbl# 
  WHERE ID = #ID#   
</cfquery>
```

Then, I attempt to display the query output:

EITHER AS

```
<cfoutput>
  <p>#cfqGetItem.field1#
  <p>#cfqGetItem.field2#
</cfoutput>
```

OR, AS

```
<cfoutput>
  <p>#cfqGetItem[field1][currentRow]#
  <p>#cfqGetItem[field2][currentRow]#
</cfoutput>
```

In each case, I get a similar CF error message: "Element field1 is not defined in query cfqGetItem", or "Variable currentrow is not defined".

How can I get the query output to generate the actual values for the record instead of the variable names?

Thank you very much for any help!

Comment: Not related to your question, but ..  why are you making the query table and column names dynamic? Depending on the source of those value, that kind of dynamic sql can expose your database to [sql injection](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/SQL_injection). (For that same reason, always use [cfqueryparam](http://help.adobe.com/en_US/ColdFusion/9.0/CFMLRef/WSc3ff6d0ea77859461172e0811cbec22c24-7f6f.html) with user supplied values like `FORM.ID`). Honestly you should avoid using dynamic sql altogether until you have a firmer grasp of whether it is really necessary .. and the risks risks involved.

Comment: *First, I define some variables* Also, there is no need to create another variable. Just use `FORM.ID` directly in your query - wrapped in cfqueryparam of course ie `WHERE ID = <cfqueryparam value="#FORM.ID#" cfsqltype="cf_sql_integer">`

Comment: *RE: have is a single "universal" page* Just my $0.02, but ... creating dynamic pages is difficult to do "well" IMO. It requires a lot of thought and planning. It is one of those things that always seems like it will make life easier, but often ends up making it more difficult in the long run. Any dynamic code is going to be a *bit* harder to maintain and debug. When it is poorly designed, those tasks become even harder. Having worked with one legacy application similar to this, I can say it was not fun to maintain. So be sure to consider all the factors when deciding on an approach.

Answer (score 0):

If you change this:

```
<cfoutput>
<p>#cfqGetItem[field1][currentRow]#
<p>#cfqGetItem[field2][currentRow]#
</cfoutput>
```

to this:

```
<cfoutput>
<cfloop query="cfqGetItem">
<p>#cfqGetItem[field1][currentRow]#
<p>#cfqGetItem[field2][currentRow]#
</cfloop>
</cfoutput>
```

You should be ok.  However, this is the simplest way

```
<cfoutput query="cfqGetItem">
<p>#actual_fieldname1#
<p>#actual_fieldname1#
</cfoutput>
```

Setting the table and field names to variables complicates matters.  Unless they really can vary, don't do it.   Also, the cfqueryparam tag is your friend.  Use it in places like this:

```
where id = <cfqueryparam
cfsqltype = "cf_sql_integer"
value = "#id#">
```

Comment: Based on the original example, there is no reason to use `cfloop`.  Just use the second example with `<cfoutput query="...">`

Answer (score 0):

You can try out like this also:

```
            <cfquery 
                name="GetParks" datasource="cfdocexamples" 
               >
                SELECT PARKNAME, REGION, STATE
                FROM Parks
                ORDER BY ParkName, State
            </cfquery>



            <cfoutput>
              <p>#GetParks.PARKNAME#
              <p>#GetParks.REGION#
            </cfoutput>


            <cfoutput >
              #GetParks['state'][GetParks.RecordCount]#
            </cfoutput>

            <cfoutput >
              #GetParks['state'][2]#
            </cfoutput>
```